# What happens if view id change dynamically in android?

Tags: android, textview

Suppose that I have a `TextView` and I am assigning it's id in xml like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextViewId"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>
```

Now I am getting the `TextView` reference and change the reference like this way.

```
    TextView myTextView =findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
    myTextView.setId(50);
```

Now my question is what happens if I want to get the TextView in another activity using this `myTextViewId`id? Is the id changing affects the original view id that is already defined in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Now my question is what happens if I want to get the same TextView in another activity?
```

You can't get the same textview in another activity. You can pass the text in textview to another activity.

If you are using textview in the same activity there is no nee for     `myTextView.setId(50);`

Check

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching.

So if you have different layouts for different activities with textview ids same there is no problem